# Mongoengine keep create key with null value even though the value is None

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongoengine

Here is my main code

```
from mongoengine import *
from models import Video
from env import ENV

connect(
   db='isysrg_inference',
   host=ENV.DB_HOST,
   port=int(ENV.DB_PORT),
)

# Construct response
video = Video(
               video_id=123,
               filename='foo',
               progress=None,
               bytes_size=1234,
               width=1,
               height=2,
               frame_total=3,
               original_video_path='foo.mp4',
               processed_video_path=None)

print(video.to_json())
```

Here is Video model

```
from mongoengine import IntField, StringField, FloatField
from .BaseModel import BaseModel
class Video(BaseModel):
  meta = {
    'collection': 'video'
  }

  video_id = IntField()
  filename = StringField()
  progress = FloatField(required=True)
  bytes_size = IntField()
  width = IntField()
  height = IntField()
  frame_total = IntField()
  original_video_path = StringField()
  processed_video_path = StringField()
```

Here is the output:

```
{"_cls": "Video", "video_id": 123, "filename": "foo", "bytes_size": 1234, "width": 1, "height": 2, "frame_total": 3, "original_video_path": "foo.mp4"}
```

I expect the output will be:

```
{"_cls": "Video", "video_id": 123, "filename": "foo", "progress":null,"bytes_size": 1234, "width": 1, "height": 2, "frame_total": 3, "original_video_path": "foo.mp4", "processed_video_path":null}
```

So how do I keep create the key such as `processed_video_path` and `progress` even though I set value None. I just want consistent database format.